# How can I get background color to only a list in html?

Tags: html, html-lists

How do I get background color to only [text of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnddQ.png) in html? I want to add background color to text of list, but I could not. I did some research but all of them didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

list hover code after add background color
and also use background transplant

if you can not understand follow this link
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-remove-the-background-colors-from-a-drop-list-when-hovering-with-HTML-and-CSS?q=How%20can%20I%20get%20background%20color%20to%20only%20a%20list%20in%20html%3F